# Unable to access core data file

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have an app which is completely based on Objective C which uses core data. I rewritten the full app in swift and I am using Relam now for swift application. when users upgrade from Objective C to swift application I want to migrate some of the DB from core data to Realm. But I am unable to access the Core data file.

Both apps are having same bundle Identifiers.

```
Objective C version:
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"StoreName" withExtension:@"momd"];

Swift Version:
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "StoreName", withExtension: "momd")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ios 10 above follow the below appoarach

```
  lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
                 let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "StoreName")
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                      })
            return container
        }()
```

Use the below method for getting context

```
  func context() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            return persistentContainer.viewContext
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            return managedObjectContext
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Comment: I am in some what same situation. I have Objective-C project live and designed completely new project in swift from scratch. I don't know how to migrate is this scenario. @santhosh did you find solution? Thanks in advance!